# django date widget that warns if date is outside a range

Tags: django-forms

I could use help finding a solution to the following.  My form has a birthdate field and uses a datepicker.  The requirement is now to alert if the person's age is less than 15 or greater than 75.  The alert is of the type, *the person's age is X, are you sure you want this*, with a Y/N type response.  If Y, leave the data in.  If N, reset the field to blank.  Or something like this.

Now I can do this with JS, but here's my rub.  I've created a single template for the forms, and am trying not to pollute it with js tied to a specific field of a specific form.

I'm guessing the best approach is to use a custom widget?  Does anyone recommend a widget that does something like this?  What I've found are widgets that limit input to ranges, which isn't quite right for my situation.  Otherwise, can someone identify an example that I might use as a guide.

Thanks.